# @Import - An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

```
@Configuration
@Import(UserpassportConfig::class)
class UvdConfig
```

Hello I have problem with gradle command: "gradlew clean build" - I got this error:

```
e: config\UvdConfig.kt: (5, 22): Unresolved reference: userpassport
e: config\UvdConfig.kt: (12, 9): Unresolved reference: UserpassportConfig
e: config\UvdConfig.kt: (12, 9): An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: not trying to pass a class type as an argument

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand you,  annotation @Import has arguments only class type

Comment: why the error: `e: config\UvdConfig.kt: (5, 22): Unresolved reference: userpassport` what is on 5th line in your file?

Comment: This is the 5th line: "import (...).config.UserpassportConfig"

Comment: try just putting it as UserpassportConfig.class

Comment: I think that in the obfuscated packages from last message you have `userpassport` which is actually the thing that can not be resolved. I also believe that, due to this unsuccessful resolution of import you are getting the rest of the errors.

Comment: Indeed this is the 5th line: "import (...)userpassport.config.UserpassportConfig"

Comment: ok, so that is the problem. fix your build so that that class is on your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my analysis from the comments to an answer, so that the question is not left hanging without answer:

I think the root of the problem manifests on the following error line: `e: config\UvdConfig.kt: (5, 22): Unresolved reference: userpassport` . Apparently the package where `UserpassportConfig` is situated is not on your build path. Thus the class is not properly imported and this causes the later errors that you see.